# How to terminate AWS Batch Job from spring boot batch application

Tags: spring-batch, aws-batch

I have setup AWS batch job.
We have one application which is responsible to creating job.
When i submit any job, that application spin up the container. So, the job will be executed(spring batch application).
Now when job is completed successfully I want to terminate the container/terminate the aws batch job from my spring batch code.
I am looking for the solution for this.

I want to terminate aws batch job from spring batch application when the process is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can terminate the spring application itself after the task completion as explained here https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-runtime/src/main/java/com/baeldung/shutdown.

```java
SpringApplication.exit(context, () -> 0);
System.exit(0);
```

[image]

Or else you can write a lambda function which can stop the aws batch as explained here. https://github.com/s7anley/aws-ecs-service-stop-lambda/blob/master/main.py